# Performance penalty in executing native SQL in Strongloop Loopback

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

Is there any disadvantage to execute native SQL query using either {dataSource.connector.execute(sql, params, cb) or dataSource.connector.query(sql, params, cb)} than using connected models?

I have recently tested the same scenario with sample data with both Native SQL and connected models. When I used Native SQL I noticed that MYSQL connection get lost when I increase the load. But The same operations performance with Loopback's connected models and filters, It can sustain almost 4 times the load compared to Native SQL Connector.

Loopback also don't recommend using Native SQL Connector:

> This feature has not been fully tested and is not officially
>   supported: the API may change in future releases. In general, it is
>   always better to perform database actions through connected models.
>   Directly executing SQL may lead to unexpected results, corrupted data,
>   and other issues. - [Loopback](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Executing+native+SQL)

So My exact question is Has anybody noticed any Disadvantage or performance panalty Using of Using Native SQL instead of Loopback's connected models?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put running raw queries(Native sql) may be faster than having using ORMs(models) as they perform validations , build queries from parameters and filters you provide etc. where as running raw queries simply issue the query to the connected sql server over network without going through all those extra layers , but those difference maybe barely noticeable. Now industry standard is that you should use ORMs(models) to access you data as they protect you from a lot of threats like sql injection and simple human errors as it performs comprehensive validations based on the schema. So simply put ORMs are safer than Raw queries. But its a matter of choice what you want to do. I honestly fall somewhere in the middle where i use ORM provided models whenever possible but i have found some instances where running Raw queries brings far more simplicity like when you have to perform joins on more than 2 tables as well as manipulate the data using queries than use ORM. This last bit is just my way of doing things which in many peoples opinion may be wrong. I suggest use ORMs ie. in your case Strong Loop connectors as much as possible.

Comment: You resoning is totally understandable, But my sample test give me exact opposite of what you saying. SQL conection breaks more frequest when Native SQL query is used, while ORMs sustains more load. (Can sustain up to 256 request per second with AWS nano instance)